# angle of skin tone line on vectorscope

Tags: color-correction

Some vectorscopes have a skin tone line to guide the correct color of human skins. However other vectorscope such as that built in FFmpeg does not have the skin tone line.

Is there a standard of the skin tone line?
What is the angle of the skin tone line?
Is there a difference between 601 and 709 color spaces?

Comment: I had a discussion on [another thread](https://github.com/norihiro/obs-color-monitor/issues/3) after posting this question. What I found is that the line varies on tools around 32 to 34 degrees at BT.709 color space.